# How to confirm edits not in my expertise field?

Tags: feature-request, questions, edits, confirmation

Most of the edited content I am offered to approve by the system is really what I do not have expertise in.

For example I get many edited questions/answers from Java tagged questions even though I don't visit Java questions nor do I have a favourite tag?

For now I simply skip them but there are a lot of them. How could I solve this?

Comment: Skipping is just fine

Comment: If I'm not comfortable with a review, I just Skip. I think a lot of edits don't need specific knowledge, but where they do, I Skip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can filter out the edits as per the tag you are specialised in 
(max 3 tags) of your choice..

[image]